# JSON file set content type to application/json AFNetworking

Tags: ios, json, mime-types, content-type, afnetworking

i wrote a .json file and want to download it with AFNetworking. But AFNetworking complains:
fail Expected content type {(
    "text/json",
    "application/json",
    "text/javascript"
)}, got text/plain

my JSON file test.json

```
{
"count-packages": 5,
"packages": 
{
    "de":
    {
        "0": "Wackel Dackel",
        "1": "Hans Wurst",
        "2": "Peter Ploes",
        "3": "Tiffel Toffel",
        "4": "China Mann"
    },
    "en":
    {
        "0": "Wobble dachshund",
        "1": "Hans Sausage",
        "2": "Peter Ploes",
        "3": "Tiffel Potato",
        "4": "Peking Ente"
    }
}
```

}

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 06 Feb 2012 17:31:06 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.41 Ben-SSL/1.59
Last-Modified: Mon, 06 Feb 2012 17:28:13 GMT
ETag: "18039c71-205-4f300dad"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 517
Content-Type: text/plain
```

How can I change the Content-Type?

Comment: I found a bug in the AFNetworking class AFHTTPRequestOperation method -(BOOL)hasAcceptableContentType

   

     - (BOOL)hasAcceptableContentType {
        return !self.acceptableContentTypes || [self.acceptableContentTypes containsObject:[self.response MIMEType]];

to 


    - (BOOL)hasAcceptableContentType {
        NSLog(@"mime type %@", [self.response MIMEType]);
        return !self.acceptableContentTypes || [self.acceptableContentTypes member:[self.response MIMEType]];
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the issue on the server side. If you have control to the Apache server, add following line in `httpd.conf`

```
application/json            json
```

EDIT : I was wrong of the syntax with my answer above. The lines like above should go into `mime.types` file as @James suggests. But you can use `AddType` directive and specify mime types in `httpd.conf` as well.

```
AddType application/json .json
```

Comment: Wrong file. It's mime.types that contains these mappings.

Comment: Thanks @James, I stand corrected. But it is also possible to specify in httpd.conf with slightly different syntax. I edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: You shouldn't change the mime.types files because if you upgrade the server this file will be overwritten as said in [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#typesconfig) so the **EDIT** is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add an appropriate entry for .json to the Apache mime.types file. See [Setting up MIME Types with Apache](http://www.developershome.com/wap/wapServerSetup/tutorial.asp?page=settingUpMIME)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to `httpd.conf` (like in many cases) you can create a `.htaccess` file and simply write `AddType application/json .json` inside. Put it next your json file and it should be OK !

Comment: To create a `.file` (like `.htaccess`) in Windows see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12298593/742855

Answer (score -1):

You can't change the content type for a .json file. Probably the error comes from the javascript, ther you sould change or parse as Json

Comment: You are not correct. You can change the content type that a web server supplies for a file.