# How to create a .gitignore file

Tags: git, xcode4.3, gitignore

I need to add some rules to my `.gitignore` file. However, I can't find it in my project folder. Isn't it created automatically by Xcode? If not, what command allows me to create one?

Comment: echo 'xxx' > .gitignore

Comment: https://www.gitignore.io/

Comment: Copy the `.gitignore` file from one of your existing projects.

Comment: how about migrating the question to superuser?

Comment: So they fixed [this apparently!](https://twitter.com/jenmsft/status/1099337661196587008?s=21)

Comment: Where is the more general question (that is not [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode)-specific) - as general Google searches (without Xcode) seems to lead here?

Comment: Some candidates: *[How to ignore certain files in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308610)*, *[How do I ignore files in a directory in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527597)*, and *[Git - Creating a .gitignore file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050487)*

Comment: More tool-specific ones: *[How to create a .gitignore file in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207907)* and *[How do I ignore all files in a folder with a Git repository in Sourcetree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665399)*

Comment: https://github.com/czheo/gitignorepy I created this tool several years ago

Answer (score 1815):

If you're using Windows, it will not let you create a file without a filename in Windows Explorer. It will give you the error "*You must type a file name*" if you try to rename a text file as **.gitignore**

[image]

To get around this, I used the following steps.

1. Create the text file *gitignore.txt*
2. Open it in a text editor and add your rules, then save and close
3. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, right click the folder you're in, and then select **Open command window here**
4. Then rename the file in the command line, with `ren gitignore.txt .gitignore`

Alternatively, [HenningCash suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744305/how-to-create-a-gitignore-file#comment23650991_12298593) in the comments:

> You can get around this Windows Explorer error by appending a dot to
> the filename without an extension: `.gitignore.`. It will be automatically
> changed to `.gitignore`.

Comment: To do this on a mac, simply CD to the project directory and "touch .gitignore" you will have to also make sure you can see hidden files

Comment: After creating the gitignore.txt file "ren" did not work for me. However I just opened the Git Bash on the directory and was able to use the linux "mv" command like normal.

Comment: i used `cp gitignore.txt .gitignore` in gitbash and then deleted the original file. mv command sounds like a better option to me :)

Comment: You can get around this Windows Explorer error by appending a dot to the filename without extension: `.gitignore.` will be automatically changed to `.gitignore` (Win7 x64)

Comment: You can also create ".gitignore" from any Windows text editor, using "Save As".

Comment: I found that `$touch .gitignore` worked from GitBash.

Comment: Funny thing that the OP is using XCode which means he's running OS X. And ya all upvoting an answer targeted on Windows?!!

Comment: The question is about XCode and it runs in Mac OS X, but this answer is for windows. so a -1 from me.

Comment: If your file is hidden `ren` says file not found. If you make your file not hidden then it works. FYI

Comment: Its funny how google disagrees, a google search ".gitignore on windows" leads to this page as a first result :)

Comment: for lazy people like me I create the file in notepad++ and saved no questions asked :)

Comment: Yes if you have any code editor, just create a new file and name it .gitignore. This is i think the easiest way as most of the editors helps doing so

Comment: I didn't know that I _can open command prompt_ in that folder just by holding SHIFT key and selecting from context menu. Thanks

Comment: @Saharsh Exactly, don't know why this isn't the actual answer!

Comment: Simply run "notepad .gitignore"

Comment: So, is it kinda... a bug of Windows?

Comment: Looks like they fixed it

Comment: Create blank '.gitignore' file in CWD with PowerShell: `New-Item .gitignore.`

Comment: In what folder must the file be placed? Example this path `c:\dev\HelloGit\ ` contains my `Program.cs` the path for the git folder is `c:\dev\HelloGit\.git\ `. Must the `.gitignore` file be inside `\HelloGit\ ` or inside `\HelloGit\.git\ `?

Answer (score 629):

As simple as things can (sometimes) be: Just add the following into your preferred command-line interface (GNU Bash, [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway), etc.)

```
touch .gitignore
```

As [War pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744305/how-to-create-a-gitignore-file#comment49945670_14979265) in the comments, `touch` works on Windows as well as long as you provide the full path. This might also explain why it does not work for some users on *Windows*: The `touch` command seems to not be in the `$PATH` on some Windows versions by default.

```
C:\> "c:\program files (x86)\git\bin\touch.exe" .gitignore
```

*Note: The path might differ, depending on your setup and installation path.*

Comment: this didn't work for me, it said touch isn't a program

Comment: I just tried it both in `cmd` and `powershell` in Windows 7 without a problem. Then tried it again on the 8.1 machine of a colleague and can confirm that (the Cmdlet isn't present). You will have to search up the problem for that as this will bite you anyway with other things as well. In short: I'm sorry for you :/

Comment: fyi - Windows does not have a native touch command.  The closest equivalent in Windows is "copy /b filename.ext +,," (where filename.ext is your file's name).  The +,, is a special flag to copy telling it to simply update the date/time on the file.  http://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch

Comment: @SpencerKillen you need to use this command by using git bash.

Comment: Works in command line if you specify the full path for touch ... C:\> "c:\program files (x86)\git\bin\touch.exe" .gitignore

Comment: worked for me in windows 10 64 bit machine from git bash

Comment: Easiest way to get Git Bash is to install Github app, it will install Git Shell as well.

Comment: for folks who are coming from Mac, use what they have said above 'touch touch .gitignore'. Then, vi .gitignore. This will open up your editor. Then visit https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore to get the ignore contents. Use Cmd + C to copy and Cmd + V on the editor open in your terminal and then :wq (save and quit) and you are good to go.

Comment: `Windows doesn’t have a native “touch” equivalent, which is a native Linux program that allows you to create empty files and change timestamps`

Comment: That's how it works, wondering why so many people are posting many different answers.

Comment: Touch might be in this path instead - C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin

Answer (score 331):

The easiest way to create the .gitignore file in Windows Explorer is to create a new file named `.gitignore.`.

This will skip the validation of having a file extension, since it actually has an empty file extension.

Comment: Definitely the easiest way, if you want to stay in pure Windows style. . .

Comment: This, is the best way for the laziest among us :D

Comment: This worked great for me. Windows actually removed the last . so the file name was changed to just .gitignore when I saved the change.

Comment: This is the real answer to what appears to be a bug in windows explorer... although I assume the original question is osx

Comment: if you move your project to linux system for example it will keep the dot at the end of the file, for me this is not a good method, always stick with the standard naming conventions, everyone who asks how to make a `.gitignore` has the skill to open a text-editor and create a `.gitignore` file without extra risky hacks.

Comment: The question mentioned Xcode which run on OSX. This does not work on OSX. (There is no Windows Explorer on OSX.)

Comment: Yes! This is the real answer. Let everybody vote this answer for others.

Comment: Similar answer: [tanguy_k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744305/how-to-create-a-gitignore-file/26484621#26484621)

Answer (score 214):

The *.gitignore* file is not added to a repository by default. Use [vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) or your favorite text editor to create the .gitignore file then issue a `git add .gitignore` followed by `git commit -m "message" .gitignore`. The following commands will take care of it.

```
> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "message" .gitignore
```

Comment: Hi, thanx for your reply :), actually, i have created a .gitignore file, but when performing this command line: `git add .gitignore`, i got this message: `fatal: pathspec '.gitignore' did not match any files
`, although, i make sure the .gitignore file does exist on my project folder, am i wrong ?

Comment: If git says the file doesn't exist - the file you've created has a different name. you can see all files in a folder with `ls -la`. Add to the question what you did (details) if you're still struggling

Comment: My .gitignore file was existing already.
I just added a rule to ignore eclipse.prefs and .log files
Committed it. Will it start working immediately?

Comment: Very helpful. Also, this method works similarly with renaming folders/directories too (not just files). For instance `Z:\pristine-vagrant>ren "New folder" .ssh`

Comment: In case of 'fatal: pathspec..' error, I simply ran git fetch then tried again git commit and push. It worked.

Answer (score 158):

#### In Windows

1. Open [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29).
2. Add the contents of your gitignore file.
3. Click "Save as" and select "all files".
4. Save as `.gitignore`

Easy peasy! No command line required!

Comment: NotePad++ is happy with this also for those that use it.

Answer (score 60):

### macOS and Linux one-liner

An easy way to get a default Git ignore without messing about with create/copy/paste is to use the `curl` command from the terminal. First `cd` into your projects root directory and then run the command by replacing `MY_API_NAME` with your API name from one of the following two sources:

#### [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/)

```
curl -o .gitignore https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/MY_API_NAME
```

You can find your API name by searching from the list [here](https://www.gitignore.io/) and clicking *Generate*.

*Java Example:*

```
curl -o .gitignore https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/java
```

#### [GitHub](https://github.com/github/gitignore)

Alternatively, you can use the ones at GitHub. Find the filename for your API [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore).

```
curl -o .gitignore https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/MY_API_NAME.gitignore
```

*Java Example:*

```
curl -o .gitignore https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/Java.gitignore
```

### Windows

Here are some similar alternatives for Windows.

- [How do I install/set up and use cURL on a Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/how-do-i-install-set-up-and-use-curl-on-a-windows)
- [Wget/cURL alternative native to Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/299754/wget-curl-alternative-native-to-windows)

But honestly setting that up looks like more trouble that it is worth. If I had Windows then I would just create an empty file called `.gitignore` in my project's root folder and then copy and paste the default text from *gitignore.io* or GitHub.

Comment: Awesome! Just what I were looking for. I recommend ConEmu that is a window terminal that support curl. https://conemu.github.io/

Answer (score 58):

On Windows, you can use cmd:

`echo "" >.gitignore`

Or use Git Bash cmd:

`touch .gitignore`,

This useful for a Linux and Mac system.

Comment: echo > .gitignore works well. To continue to append the files to ignore, we can do echo "*.obj" >> .gitignore

Comment: I would be careful about using this approach. On my computer, running Windows 10, using echo to create .gitignore resulted in a UTF 16LE formatted file, which Git apparently did not parse correctly. Creating the file through Windows Explorer resulted in an ANSI formatted file, which worked correctly with Git.

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 53):

I want my contribution as well. This time, animated one :)

[Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) (mini tutorial):

```
i   - start editing
ESC - get back to normal mode
:w  - save
:q  - quit
```

[image]

Answer (score 45):

Using the [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) console.

- Navigate to your project
- Type "touch .gitignore"

The *.gitignore* file will be created for you.

[image]

Answer (score 35):

*My contribution is aimed at those on a Mac, and it can be applied to not only those working on an iOS project (as implied by the question mentioning Xcode), but any type of project.*

---

The easy way that I do it is to go into the terminal and run `vim .gitignore` and then add the files. Usually you can just copy what you need from one of the templates on GitHub at https://github.com/github/gitignore.

**Step 1**
While in your project, type the following command

```
vim .gitignore
```

[image]

**Step 2**
You now have your file open with [Vim](http://www.vim.org/about.php).

[image]

Press `i` to insert text. You will see that the file is ready when you see the **--INSERT--** at the bottom.

[image]

**Step 3 (option 1)**
For Objective-C projects, you can copy from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/Objective-C.gitignore and paste it into your `.gitignore` file:

[image]

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, type in `:wq`, and press <kbd>Return</kbd>. Which saves the file.

**Step 3 (option 2)**
Add whatever files apply to your project.

If you are not sure what to add, the best keywords to use in your search engine would be to include your project type and text editor. For example, if you use [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) you would want to add

```
*.sublime-workspace
```

And if you are working with a [Cordova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cordova) project in [Dreamweaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Dreamweaver) you would want to add

```
_notes
dwsync.xml
```

Answer (score 32):

Here a nice tip under Windows:

- Right click in Windows Explorer, New > Text Document
- Name it .gitignore. (with a trailing dot - that is the tip)
- You end up with a .gitignore file :)

Tested under Windows 7 and 8.

This tip assumes that your Windows Explorer displays the file extensions.

[image: Windows Explorer .gitignore]

Comment: Similar answer: [chos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744305/how-to-create-a-gitignore-file/17837041#17837041)

Answer (score 18):

Create a .gitignore file in include all files and directories that you don't want to commit.

Example:

```
#################
## Eclipse
#################

*.pydevproject
.project
.metadata
.gradle
bin/
tmp/
target/
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.classpath
.settings/
.loadpath

# External tool builders
.externalToolBuilders/

# Locally stored "Eclipse launch configurations"
*.launch

# CDT-specific
.cproject

# PDT-specific
.buildpath


#################
## Visual Studio
#################

## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

# Build results

[Dd]ebug/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
build/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

# MSTest test Results
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.log
*.scc

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx

# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper

# TeamCity is a build add-in
_TeamCity*

# DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
*.dotCover

# NCrunch
*.ncrunch*
.*crunch*.local.xml

# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

# Click-Once directory
publish/

# Publish Web Output
*.Publish.xml
*.pubxml

# NuGet Packages Directory
## TODO: If you have NuGet Package Restore enabled, uncomment the next line
#packages/

# Windows Azure Build Output
csx
*.build.csdef

# Windows Store app package directory
AppPackages/

# Others
sql/
*.Cache
ClientBin/
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.pfx
*.publishsettings
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question was about ***how to create*** the file, not about the content of the file.

Answer (score 16):

**http://gitignore.io** is an open source utility that can help you create useful .gitignore files for your project. There is also a command line API that you can access via a `gi` command: http://gitignore.io/cli

1. Install `gi` command for **OS X**:

   `$ echo "function gi() { curl http://gitignore.io/api/\$@ ;}" >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile`
2. View .gitignore file contents (Output: http://gitignore.io/api/xcode,osx):

   `$ gi xcode,osx`
3. You should see output on the terminal, if you want to append the results to a new .gitignore file.

   `$ gi xcode,osx >> .gitignore`

Answer (score 16):

I have another simple idea.

Let's use the [echo](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) command in [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe),

`echo ./idea > .gitignore`

This will create the *.gitignore* file having text content "./idea".

You may now manually change data from the file using a text editor.

Or simply

Console:

```
echo .gitignore notepad.exe
```

to instantly edit gitignore.

If you don’t know which files are should be *gitignored* for your IDE or operating system just go to *[www.gitignore.io](http://www.gitignore.io)*.

> [gitignore.io     -   here it will generate the gitignore commands or text for you. Just say your API or OS. That’s it!. Just copy and paste into your file. Simple!](http://gitignore.io)

Answer (score 15):

You can go to *[Create Useful .gitignore Files For Your Project](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore)*.

Select the IDE, operating systems or programming language. It will automatically generate one for you.

[image]

Comment: This has already been covered in several previous answers.

Answer (score 14):

Here's my personal favorite, http://help.github.com/ignore-files/

Also just in case you wanted to ignore Xcode files, refer to [an answer to *Git ignore file for Xcode projects*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects/49488#49488).

Comment: You ought to put the essential information in your answer, so it is not all reliant on the link not breaking.

Answer (score 12):

In Windows, open a DOS prompt (cmd) window, and use this command line:

```
type > .gitignore
```

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to have your *.gitignore* file interfere with anyone else's repository, you can also use `.git/info/exclude` (see http://help.github.com/ignore-files/).

Answer (score 10):

The following works in PowerShell and a command prompt (CMD):

```
echo '*.ignore_me' > .gitignore
```

I ran into a weird issue where Git effectively wouldn't read the .gitignore file. I then deleted the .gitignore file and created one using Vim which worked fine.

To add additional files to ignore, just call the following command:

```
echo 'another_file_to_ignore' >> .gitignore
```

It will append further files to the existing .gitignore file.

Comment: I had the same weird issue. Turns out to be the encoding, so be sure to save the file as utf-8.

Answer (score 10):

### A few ways to create file *.gitignore* using cmd:

#### With the `copy con` command:

1. open **cmd** and type `cd` to your Git repository
2. Type `copy con .gitignore` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>.

   [image]

#### With the `start notepad .gitignore` command

1. Open **cmd** and type `cd` to your Git repository
2. Type `start notepad .gitignore` and press the <kbd>Yes</kbd> button in the opened Notepad dialog box.

   [image]

#### With the `edit .gitignore` command (Windows x86 only)

1. Open **cmd** and type `cd` to your Git repository
2. Type `edit .gitignore` and close the opened 'edit' editor.

Answer (score 10):

#### Windows

[image]

> *File name*: ".gitignore", 
> *Save as type*: *All Files* (*.*)

Answer (score 9):

1. To create a .gitignore file, you just create a .txt file and change the extension as in the following:

[image]

Then you have to change the name, writing the following line on the cmd:

```
 rename git.txt .gitignore
```

where *git.txt* is the name of the file you've just created.

Then you can open the file and write all the files you don’t want to add on the repository. For example, mine looks like this:

```
# OS junk files
[Tt]humbs.db
*.DS_Store

# Visual Studio files
*.[Oo]bj
*.user
*.aps
*.pch
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ncb
*.suo
*.tlb
*.tlh
*.bak
*.[Cc]ache
*.ilk
*.log
*.lib
*.sbr
*.sdf
*.pyc
*.xml
ipch/
obj/
[Bb]in
[Dd]ebug*/
[Rr]elease*/
Ankh.NoLoad

# Tooling
_ReSharper*/
*.resharper
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*

# Project files
[Bb]uild/

# Subversion files
.svn

# Office Temp Files
~$*
```

Once you have this, you need to add it to your Git repository. You have to save the file where your repository is.

Then in your [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway), you have to write the following line:

[image]

If the repository already exists, you have to do the following:

1. `git rm -r --cached .`
2. `git add .`
3. `git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"`

If step 2 doesn’t work then you should write the whole route of the files that you would like to add.

Comment: Finally an answer that shows what syntax is used within the .gitignore file.

Answer (score 9):

Do:

1. Open a Git terminal
2. Go to the Git repository of the project
3. Create a *.gitignore* file by **touch .gitignore** command
4. Use **git add .gitignore** command to add the ignore file
5. Set ignore rules in the ignore file
6. Run the command **cat .gitignore**

By running the command in step 3, you will get the *.gitignore* file in the project directory.

Answer (score 9):

You can directly create an empty `.gitignore` file. Open `cmd` in the location you need to add this file to, and type this command:

```
copy con .gitignore
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. We are now in edit mode of the newly created file, but we do not need to add anything now. Just press <kbd>F6</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now you have an empty `.gitignore` file. Edit your file in whatever editor you have.

Comment: `copy nul .gitignore` is better

Comment: yes it does the work faster, thank you for the info.

Comment: You can create .gitignore file in notepad by using ".gitignore" as file name when saving the file and notice the "" , notepad will then take the whole string between the quotation to save your file as the selected name

Answer (score 8):

Windows:

On the command line:

```
.>.gitignore
```

This will show an error, but it will work.

Comment: What error will it show? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53093031/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the first dot in the command line for? [Standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin))? What does it mean? How does it work? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53093031/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Wish there was a way to ignore this git.

Answer (score 8):

To add `.gitignore` file to your not application you can use the

```
> npx add-gitignore
```

Now you can type `"node"` and use user space bar to choose it and Enter.
That will add the node `.gitignore` to the project.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *"your not application"*? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61169957/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way***, *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66101455/edit) (it covers answers and terminal output as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Without using the command line (on Windows)

1. Open any texteditor (e.g. Notepad) and add your rules.
2. Click menu *File* → *Save As*
3. Save it as ".gitignore" (include the quotations)

Comment: What text editor exactly? Do you mean "[Text Editor](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/gedit)" (repackaged [gedit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedit))? What platform (operating system and edition), incl. versions, was this tried on? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34237832/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 4):

At work we are on [Windows XP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP), and typing a period at the end of a filename doesn't work. A quick and easy way to create a .gitignore file without having the "You must type a filename"error is:

1. open a [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) window and type "edit .gitignore".
2. type "Alt (selects file menu), F, S.  You now have an empty .gitignore file wherever your cmd prompt is pointing.

You can now populate it with your favorite text editor.

Answer (score 4):

To add any file in Xcode, go to the menu and navigate to
menu *File* → *New* → *File*...

For a .gitignore file choose *Other* → *Empty* and click on *Next*.
Type in the name (.gitignore) into the *Save As* field and click *Create*.

For files starting with a dot (".") a warning message will pop up, telling you that the file will be hidden. Just click on *Use "."* to proceed...

That's all.

To fill your brand new .gitignore you can find an example for ignoring Xcode file here: *[Git ignore file for Xcode projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects/12021580#12021580)*

Answer (score 4):

If you use [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) as your IDE, you can create a new file and save it as .gitignore. Simply using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> for the new file, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save as ".gitignore".

Answer (score 4):

You can type `new-item .gitignore` in Windows PowerShell.

Answer (score 4):

There is a pretty simple way to create a *.gitignore* file. This one is created on GitHub, and I'm pretty sure that most source controls offer the feature for creating a file there itself.

I am attaching an image-by-image tutorial for reference.

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]

Answer (score 4):

Have you see this article?

[Easy to create `.gitignore` for the dotnet developers](https://dev.to/rafalpienkowski/easy-to-create-gitignore-for-the-dotnet-developers-1h42)

It mentions:

> Starting from .Net Core 3.0, you can take advantage of the build in
> the .Net framework `gitignore` file template just by typing `dotnet new gitignore` in your terminal.

I just tried it and this is the file it created:

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.
##
## Get latest from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

# User-specific files
*.rsuser
*.suo
*.user
*.userosscache
*.sln.docstates

# User-specific files (MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio)
*.userprefs

# Mono auto generated files
mono_crash.*

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
x64/
x86/
[Ww][Ii][Nn]32/
[Aa][Rr][Mm]/
[Aa][Rr][Mm]64/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
[Ll]og/
[Ll]ogs/

# Visual Studio 2015/2017 cache/options directory
.vs/
# Uncomment if you have tasks that create the project's static files in wwwroot
#wwwroot/

# Visual Studio 2017 auto generated files
Generated\ Files/

# MSTest test Results
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

# NUnit
*.VisualState.xml
TestResult.xml
nunit-*.xml

# Build Results of an ATL Project
[Dd]ebugPS/
[Rr]eleasePS/
dlldata.c

# Benchmark Results
BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts/

# .NET
project.lock.json
project.fragment.lock.json
artifacts/

# Tye
.tye/

# ASP.NET Scaffolding
ScaffoldingReadMe.txt

# StyleCop
StyleCopReport.xml

# Files built by Visual Studio
*_i.c
*_p.c
*_h.h
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.iobj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.ipdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*_wpftmp.csproj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.svclog
*.scc

# Chutzpah Test files
_Chutzpah*

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opendb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile
*.VC.db
*.VC.VC.opendb

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx
*.sap

# Visual Studio Trace Files
*.e2e

# TFS 2012 Local Workspace
$tf/

# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper
*.DotSettings.user

# TeamCity is a build add-in
_TeamCity*

# DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
*.dotCover

# AxoCover is a Code Coverage Tool
.axoCover/*
!.axoCover/settings.json

# Coverlet is a free, cross platform Code Coverage Tool
coverage*.json
coverage*.xml
coverage*.info

# Visual Studio code coverage results
*.coverage
*.coveragexml

# NCrunch
_NCrunch_*
.*crunch*.local.xml
nCrunchTemp_*

# MightyMoose
*.mm.*
AutoTest.Net/

# Web workbench (sass)
.sass-cache/

# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

# Click-Once directory
publish/

# Publish Web Output
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.azurePubxml
# Note: Comment the next line if you want to checkin your web deploy settings,
# but database connection strings (with potential passwords) will be unencrypted
*.pubxml
*.publishproj

# Microsoft Azure Web App publish settings. Comment the next line if you want to
# checkin your Azure Web App publish settings, but sensitive information contained
# in these scripts will be unencrypted
PublishScripts/

# NuGet Packages
*.nupkg
# NuGet Symbol Packages
*.snupkg
# The packages folder can be ignored because of Package Restore
**/[Pp]ackages/*
# except build/, which is used as an MSBuild target.
!**/[Pp]ackages/build/
# Uncomment if necessary however generally it will be regenerated when needed
#!**/[Pp]ackages/repositories.config
# NuGet v3's project.json files produces more ignorable files
*.nuget.props
*.nuget.targets

# Microsoft Azure Build Output
csx/
*.build.csdef

# Microsoft Azure Emulator
ecf/
rcf/

# Windows Store app package directories and files
AppPackages/
BundleArtifacts/
Package.StoreAssociation.xml
_pkginfo.txt
*.appx
*.appxbundle
*.appxupload

# Visual Studio cache files
# files ending in .cache can be ignored
*.[Cc]ache
# but keep track of directories ending in .cache
!?*.[Cc]ache/

# Others
ClientBin/
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.dbproj.schemaview
*.jfm
*.pfx
*.publishsettings
orleans.codegen.cs

# Including strong name files can present a security risk
# (https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/2483#issue-259490424)
#*.snk

# Since there are multiple workflows, uncomment next line to ignore bower_components
# (https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/1529#issuecomment-104372622)
#bower_components/

# RIA/Silverlight projects
Generated_Code/

# Backup & report files from converting an old project file
# to a newer Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed,
# because we have git ;-)
_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm
ServiceFabricBackup/
*.rptproj.bak

# SQL Server files
*.mdf
*.ldf
*.ndf

# Business Intelligence projects
*.rdl.data
*.bim.layout
*.bim_*.settings
*.rptproj.rsuser
*- [Bb]ackup.rdl
*- [Bb]ackup ([0-9]).rdl
*- [Bb]ackup ([0-9][0-9]).rdl

# Microsoft Fakes
FakesAssemblies/

# GhostDoc plugin setting file
*.GhostDoc.xml

# Node.js Tools for Visual Studio
.ntvs_analysis.dat
node_modules/

# Visual Studio 6 build log
*.plg

# Visual Studio 6 workspace options file
*.opt

# Visual Studio 6 auto-generated workspace file (contains which files were open etc.)
*.vbw

# Visual Studio LightSwitch build output
**/*.HTMLClient/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.DesktopClient/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.DesktopClient/ModelManifest.xml
**/*.Server/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.Server/ModelManifest.xml
_Pvt_Extensions

# Paket dependency manager
.paket/paket.exe
paket-files/

# FAKE - F# Make
.fake/

# CodeRush personal settings
.cr/personal

# Python Tools for Visual Studio (PTVS)
__pycache__/
*.pyc

# Cake - Uncomment if you are using it
# tools/**
# !tools/packages.config

# Tabs Studio
*.tss

# Telerik's JustMock configuration file
*.jmconfig

# BizTalk build output
*.btp.cs
*.btm.cs
*.odx.cs
*.xsd.cs

# OpenCover UI analysis results
OpenCover/

# Azure Stream Analytics local run output
ASALocalRun/

# MSBuild Binary and Structured Log
*.binlog

# NVidia Nsight GPU debugger configuration file
*.nvuser

# MFractors (Xamarin productivity tool) working folder
.mfractor/

# Local History for Visual Studio
.localhistory/

# BeatPulse healthcheck temp database
healthchecksdb

# Backup folder for Package Reference Convert tool in Visual Studio 2017
MigrationBackup/

# Ionide (cross platform F# VS Code tools) working folder
.ionide/

# Fody - auto-generated XML schema
FodyWeavers.xsd

##
## Visual studio for Mac
##


# globs
Makefile.in
*.userprefs
*.usertasks
config.make
config.status
aclocal.m4
install-sh
autom4te.cache/
*.tar.gz
tarballs/
test-results/

# Mac bundle stuff
*.dmg
*.app

# content below from: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/macOS.gitignore
# General
.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride

# Icon must end with two \r
Icon


# Thumbnails
._*

# Files that might appear in the root of a volume
.DocumentRevisions-V100
.fseventsd
.Spotlight-V100
.TemporaryItems
.Trashes
.VolumeIcon.icns
.com.apple.timemachine.donotpresent

# Directories potentially created on remote AFP share
.AppleDB
.AppleDesktop
Network Trash Folder
Temporary Items
.apdisk

# content below from: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Windows.gitignore
# Windows thumbnail cache files
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db
ehthumbs_vista.db

# Dump file
*.stackdump

# Folder config file
[Dd]esktop.ini

# Recycle Bin used on file shares
$RECYCLE.BIN/

# Windows Installer files
*.cab
*.msi
*.msix
*.msm
*.msp

# Windows shortcuts
*.lnk

# JetBrains Rider
.idea/
*.sln.iml

##
## Visual Studio Code
##
.vscode/*
!.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.vscode/extensions.json
```

Answer (score 3):

On Mac -

you can just create a new text file.

Add content using https://www.gitignore.io/

Save the file with file format as - Rich Text document with attachments.

Change the file name to .gitingore
and select `use"."` when a pop up comes as in the attached image.

*Note*: Since it is a hidden file, you won’t be able to see it in the directory. But it will be created.

[image: See image]

Answer (score 3):

I realize this question is focused on how to "create" the gitignore file, but in case someone is interested in a quick way to add contents to the file once it is created, here is my answer using [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) for those trying to "ignore" files that appear in their changes list.

1. Make the changes to your code which generate unwanted changes in your repository.
2. Go to GitHub Desktop and to your repository.
3. Select all the changes and right click them.
4. Add your changes to the gitignore file.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B). Use menu *File* → *New File* → *Save As* → *.gitignore* (*Save as type*: *All types(*.*)*)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Windows Explorer wouldn't allow you to create this file name. Another easy way to come around this is to create a dummy file in the directory, for example *NewFile.txt*, and then just simply rename it in [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) like the following:

```
mv NewFile.txt .gitignore
```

Comment: This works on macOS in the Terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can actually make Xcode generate it automatically, when you start a new project.

In order to do so, you'll have to start doing some harmless hacking yourself...

Before you begin: Make a backup of "Project Templates", as I predict you'll want to do more than I just mention, once you've discovered it.

Now, go to /Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates/Application/Cocoa Application/
Add your *.gitignore* file there.

That's all. When you create a new "Cocoa Application" project, then the *.gitignore* file is automatically copied from your project templates.

Beware: If you want to edit the templates themselves, use **nano** for that; do not use Xcode or TextEdit as they mess up the Unicode characters! Well, Xcode also messes up everything else.

Note: There's also a "File Templates", which you should also make a backup of before you start modifying them. Again: Use **nano** for editing them; not Xcode, nor TextEdit.

Here's one of my own .gitignore files, which you can use for inspiration:

```
.DS_Store
Icon\15
Icon\r
Icon\n
/*.xcodeproj/*.mode*
/*.xcodeproj/*.pbxuser
/*.xcodeproj/TemplateIcon.icns
/*.xcodeproj/.LSOverride
!/*.xcodeproj/default.*
/*.pbproj/*.mode*
/*.pbproj/*.pbxuser
/*.pbproj/*.perspective*
/build/
*.moved-aside
*~.nib
*~.xib
```

Note: I use Xcode 2.5 and Xcode 3.1.4 (I would prefer 3.1, but it keeps spamming my console)

Answer (score 0):

On Mac:

- open terminal and run `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES` anywhere.
- restart Finder so you can see hidden files: `command + option + escape` → `Relaunch`

Then create a text file and you will be able to change the file extension to `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

In [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), you can create the `.gitignore` file and add (ignore) all the files over 50 MB from the current directory, `.`, using:

```
find . -size +100M | cat >> .gitignore
```

Comment: This is not limited to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I created this tool several years ago: https://github.com/czheo/gitignorepy

For example, you can easily create an `.gitignore` file for C++ by running

```
gg fetch c++ > .gitignore
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a one-liner version of Linux "touch" in Windows

```
cd c:\<folder>\break
> .gitignore
```

That will create a blank .gitignore file where you can edit and add items to ignore.

```
cd C:\Users\test
dir .gitignore
```

Output:

```
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 9223-E93F

 Directory of C:\Users\test

18/04/2019  02:23 PM                 0 .gitignore
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  353,009,770,496 bytes free
```

Comment: @mburesh -- There are so many late answers here, yet you only flag this one. 