# ignoring files with a certain file name with Git

Tags: git, gitignore

I am using Dreamweaver to code (just trying it out since I am paying for Creative Cloud anyway) and it modifies dwsync.xml in the _notes folder for that directory every time there is a change..

I would like Git to ignore all files with the name dwsync.xml as it is little by little crowding up my list of changed files.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: search for [gitignore questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050487/git-creating-a-gitignore-file)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git ?

Comment: I could be wrong but the Duplicate in question was about deleting a certain file out of the repository retroactively... which is actually quite useful if I ever upload a non public file by mistake... but with this I want to ignore all instances of that file name, even if there may be many. I don't care about past ones staying, just don't want it to be uploaded every time I have a commit.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different options, in this case you probably want:

https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/#explicit-repository-excludes

> If you don't want to create a .gitignore file to share with others,
>   you can create rules that are not committed with the repository. You
>   can use this technique for locally-generated files that you don't
>   expect other users to generate, such as files created by your editor.
>
> Use your favorite text editor to open the file called
>   .git/info/exclude within the root of your Git repository. Any rule you
>   add here will not be checked in, and will only ignore files for your
>   local repository.

Answer (score 0):

Git ignore deals with such problems.So add your "to be ignored files/directories" inside it.

You can use patterns, file names , directories etc inside it.

For the above case add the following line.

> pathtoyour_notesfolder/dwsync.xml

Here is a sample `gitignore` file template for different languages.

https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: I think the trouble is with every single folder I have dreamweaver generates a dwsync.xml, so I could create a line in my gitignore for every single folder that has code as well as any other folders I make, but I was wondering if there was a */dwsync.xml that would not show any dwsync.xml files regardless of directory.
But between this and other small hassles such as lack of color coding support for SASS I am considering dropping dreamweaver.