# Git Ignoring File from Adding to Server

Tags: git, server, local, gitignore

I have local copy of my repository from Server. I have some files which i don't want to commit.

How to add that file in local to `gitignore`? So once i push my data to server, that file not added

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050487/git-creating-a-gitignore-file

Comment: Has the file or files already been committed to the repo, possibly by you or someone else?

Comment: Don't want to commit that file. To Avoid that file by Commiting

Comment: I see you want your own local ignore configuration? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/git-ignore-files-only-locally

Comment: Yes Correct @DaveThomas

Comment: I already have `.gitignore` file which is from server. I update that & Commit will that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a `.gitignore` file, all you need to do is edit it and add relative file paths (of the files that you don't want to commit) to it, one per line.

However, you might not want `commit` your `.gitignore` file, otherwise your file names, that you didn't want to commit, will be visible to everyone else.