# How can I tell git to ignore LibreOffice lock files?

Tags: git, gitignore, libreoffice

I have a git repo which contains some XSLX files. I edit them with LibreOffice every once in a while. Sometimes LibreOffice won't remove the lock files ( `./folder/.~lock.filename.xslx#`). This causes those files to be liested as new on every `git status`.

I would like git to ignore them. I tried the following in `.gitignore` but doesn't seem to work:

```
*.~lock*
.~lock*
*/.~lock*
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Also tried:

```
.~lock.*#
```

As seen in http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/libreoffice-commits/2012-December/040253.html
with no success.

Comment: `.~lock*` works for me. have you committed those files yet? `.gitignore` only works on untracked files.

Comment: `.~lock*` works for me too. Which version of Git are you using?

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Git for Windows.

Comment: ...Even if I add the *exact* .~lock file I'd like to exclude, with its full name, it still doesn't work....no idea why.

Comment: Solved....https://stackoverflow.com/a/48970642/4561887 ....1 hr lost :(. First time really using git in Windows :(...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To test patterns for `.gitignore`,

```
git ls-files -ix '.~lock*'
```

To see if any cached aka staged aka tracked aka added files match ignore patterns (and so may have been added in error),

```
git ls-files -ic --exclude-standard
```

As @NevikRehnel pointed out, git won't ignore tracked files.  To un-track a file,

```
git rm --cached path/to/it
```

which will take it out of the next commit, but the only way to take a file out of earlier history is a rewrite with e.g. [`git commit --amend`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html#_options) if it was just the last commit, [`git rebase -i`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#_interactive_mode) if you've got only a few to do or [`git filter-branch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) for bulk work.  None of those actually alters the old history, they add new history and switch any current branch to refer to it.  The old history is still there, and no other refs are moved.

Answer (score 4):

Answer (as you discovered in your comments): adding **`*.~lock*` inside the `.gitignore` file works just fine**.

Also, if using [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/), be sure to name your `.gitignore` file `.gitignore`, NOT `.gitignore.txt`, which is what Windows tries to force it to be if renaming or creating the file with Windows Explorer. To do this, save it using a text editor rather than trying to rename it in Windows Explorer ([see more on this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12298593/4561887)).

If you accidentally have the `.txt` extension at the end it will NOT work and git will NOT read the file properly as a `.gitignore` file.

For more-detailed gitignore formatting notes, and to learn the syntax of how to specify files and folders to be ignored, see my comments and examples in [my `.gitignore` file](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/.gitignore) in my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) repo.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck with this issue the entire weekend. `*.~lock*` did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

If you tried the above solutions and the did not work, please check out this link, it helped me to solve it: 
[excluding LibreOffice lock files](https://forum.syncthing.net/t/proper-way-to-exclude-libreoffice-lock-files/6696/7)

I actually ended up making making a .gitignore file, though originally I had been meaning to add them to the git "exclude" file. However I think the solution may work for that also.

**Basically the idea is to close and restart libreOffice and "cd" out your git repo and back into it again for the changes to take effect.**

I hope that helps someone else with this issue.

Comment: Please avoid linking out without also summarizing the relevant information here.