# .gitignore doesn't ignore files in subdirectories

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a *.gitignore* file in my repository top level folder with the following code:

```
# Compiled python modules.
*.pyc

# Backup gedit files.
/*~

# Setuptools distribution folder.
/dist/

# Python egg metadata, regenerated from source files by setuptools.
/*.egg-info
/*.egg
```

When I try to run a `git add .` command the *.gitignore* does not make any effect, as several /*~ are added. The output for `git status` is the following:

```
new file:   uvispace/tests/test_messenger.py
new file:   uvispace/tests/test_messenger.py~
new file:   uvispace/tests/test_robot.py~
new file:   uvispace/uvirobot/__main__.py~
new file:   uvispace/uvirobot/messenger.py~
new file:   uvispace/uvirobot/move_base.py
```

---

### Similar Questions

I have seen several very similar questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-not-working), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436312/gitignore-not-working). They solution is to remove previously added files and then add again the whole repository with the following instructions:

```
git rm -rf --cached .
git add *
```

However, I tried it and there is no difference. Anyone has an idea why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried changing `/*~` to `*~`?

Comment: @JackBracken alright that was the problem. Thank you very much!! If you put it as answer I will validate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation about the gitignore-syntax can be found here: [git-scm.com/docs/gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

One thing that probably is wrong is your **`/*~`** because the single **`*`** doesn't work the way you expect:

> For example, "Documentation/*.html" matches "Documentation/git.html" but not "Documentation/ppc/ppc.html" or "tools/perf/Documentation/perf.html".

You have to use **`**`** instead:

> •A leading "`**`" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, "`**/foo`" matches file or directory "`foo`" anywhere, the same as pattern "`foo`". "`**/foo/bar`" matches file or directory "`bar`" anywhere that is directly under directory "`foo`".
>
> •A trailing "`/**`" matches everything inside. For example, "`abc/**`" matches all files inside directory "`abc`", relative to the location of the .gitignore file, with infinite depth.
>
> •A slash followed by two consecutive asterisks then a slash matches zero or more directories. For example, "`a/**/b`" matches "`a/b`", "`a/x/b`", "`a/x/y/b`" and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove the leading slash so that the pattern `*~` will match in all directories within the repo.