# Composer: Strange behavior

Tags: git, composer-php, gitignore

I am farly new to composer. however I have been using it without any issues until now. My issues is that every time i run either composer update or install all files under my vendor folder gets into my  untracked list in git. I also have a .gitignore to prevent the "vendor" from being tracked, but apparently is not doing what is suppose to do. My .gitignore file is below.

```
# phpunit itself is not needed
phpunit.phar
# local phpunit config
/phpunit.xml

# ignore sub directory for dev installed apps and extensions
/apps
/extensions

#custom
runtime/
web/

/vendor

!vendor/dixonsatit/
!vendor/dixonsatit/yii2-agency-theme/dist/img/
!vendor/dixonsatit/yii2-agency-theme/dist/css/
```

Any tips will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First commit your current changes, then run following commands on top folder:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "fixed untracked files"
```

[Ref link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-is-not-working)
[Ref link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436312/gitignore-not-working)

Comment: I did ran those commands before, it seemed to work, meaning all vendor files got untracked. But as soon as i ran composer install/update the vendor files came back.