# Django settings.cpython-36.pyc not ignored by gitignore

Tags: python, django, git, pycharm, gitkraken

The file in my application `settings.cpython-36.pyc` is not being ignored even though I have added it to the `.gitignore` file.

My gitignore code:

```
*.log
*.pot
*.pyc
.idea
LearnDjango/__pycache__/
venv/
/LearnDjango/settings.py
LearnDjango/__pycache__/settings.cpython-36.pyc
```

[Gitkraken view, you can see it still picks it up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibtp1.png)

This line `LearnDjango/__pycache__/` in the gitignore file ignores the other `.cpython-36.pyc` files but not `settings.cpython-36.pyc`

[View of `__pycache__` folder, the 1st and 3rd files are ignored but not the 2nd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBLD7.png)

P.S 
I am new to Django and git.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was facing the same problem.

1. First, make sure that you don't have any changes to commit;
2. Edit or create your .gitignore and put the follow code:

> *.log
>
> *.pot
>
> *.pyc
>
> */*/*/__pycache__/
>
> */*/__pycache__/
>
> */__pycache__/

3. Save -> git add . -> git commit
4. 'Clean Git Hub Cache' for your repo:

> git rm -rf --cached .
>
> git add .

4. Commit and it's done!

I hope that this can help you.

Comment: Ahhh... as stated by the user Ahmad in this post, you must to clean the github cache also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25436481/4252612

Comment: After adjust gitignore, I had to do this  for every file, so I call awk for help: "git status | grep pycache | awk {'print $3'} | xargs git reset HEAD"

Answer (score 0):

add these to your gitignore and try it will work

```
*.pyc
*/*/*/__pycache__/
*/*/__pycache__/
*/__pycache__/
```

Comment: if so delete it from git and try

Comment: i am using bitbucket, its not in the the remote repo only on my local because i didnt commit that file.

Comment: try adding only this line  LearnDjango/pycache/ remove  this line and check

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use this in your project.[django project sample .gitignore file](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-project-template/blob/master/.gitignore)

Comment: It still didn't ignore the file.

Comment: simply dont push that file.unstage that file.infact files with .pyc extension dont have to be pushed on repo

Comment: That's what I am currently doing but I wanted to know what I was doing wrong.