# Ignoring certain files when pushing to github

Tags: github, git-commit, git-push

I need to ignore some files when pushing to github account. I read about git ignore. How to add files into gitignore? Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Just create a file in the root of your project all call it ".gitignore". Don't forget the dot in front of it. And then just add the name of the folders you want it to ignore. Take a look [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore ) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436312/gitignore-not-working/25436481#25436481).

Comment: I tried it and added a file name to .gitignore, but still pushing is not successful :(

Comment: Take a look again at the second link I posted (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436312/gitignore-not-working/25436481#25436481) and follow those steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following command:
git rm --cached FILENAME

refer [1].

[1] : https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/