# gitignore wildcard not working with multiple file extensions

Tags: git, gitignore, glob

Probably a repeat, but I can't find an answer.

So I have a `.gitignore` file:

```
transactions.csv
transactions_test.csv
**/test.gnucash*
test
**/test.gnucash.2*
```

And the following directory:

```
LICENSE    test.gnucash                         transactions_test.csv
main.py    test.gnucash.20180615182021.gnucash  transactions_testPUBLIC.csv
README.md  test.gnucash.20180618121545.gnucash  translations.json
test/      transactions.csv
```

However when I run `git ls-tree -r master --name-only` I get:

```
.gitignore
.vscode/settings.json
LICENSE
README.md
main.py
test.gnucash.20180615182021.gnucash
test.gnucash.20180618121545.gnucash
transactions_testPUBLIC.csv
translations.json
```

Even weirder than that, if I run this through a [glob tester](http://www.globtester.com/#p=eJzT0tIvSS0u0UvPK01OLM7QM9ICADfRBeU%3D&r=eJyzScksU0jOSSwutlVSstMPLU4tKtZPyU9P1S9LLarUT8xNrErVyyq20Qeqs7NBVVxaXKSfk5%2BcmKOflJmnX55fjlVVSWpxiV56XmlyYnEGpoLcxJLkDDRVekYGhhaGRkbGhkbGJqRqxeYGm6QiO4g4AFEzUMA%3D&), it works correctly. (see hyperlink)

Any ideas as to what's happening? I'm running Git for Windows on Windows 10.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.17.0.windows.1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gitignore not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436312/gitignore-not-working)

Comment: @phd yes, it's a duplicate of that post. I just didn't see it when I was looking at it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already added these files to git, haven't you? `.gitignore` does not affect files already known to git; it only excludes untracked files from consideration for addition.

So if you don't want to see a file, you first need to remove it from being tracked with `git rm --cached [FILE TO BE REMOVED]` (where [`--cached` will prevent git from actually deleting files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#Documentation/git-rm.txt---cached)). As noted by @Bo-G, this will not completely remove a file from a repository's history; it will still be part of earlier revisions or other branches.

Comment: That was the issue! For future stragglers (if there are any), you can use `git rm --cached [FILE TO BE REMOVED]` to remove the file from tracking and add it to `.gitignore`.

Answer (score -1):

Old post but important, even if you use `git rm --cached [FILE TO BE REMOVED]` it will still exist commit history on github, if you published secrets by mistake

Comment: FYI, this would be more appropriate as a comment (hence the downvotes right now), but seeing as you don't have enough reputation to make a comment, you're kinda stuck in a catch22. I'll add your comment onto the accepted answer.

Comment: The [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository) recommends that if you need to *COMPLETELY* delete Git objects (sensitive data, large files, etc.), use `git filter-branch` or [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).