# Strange behavior of .gitignore exclude folder

Tags: git

I have read [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore) guide and says:

[image]

Why is the directory "Timer/RoutineTimer/.idea/" not ignored in my repository?

[My repository](https://github.com/christianrocchetti/Timer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To un-track a committed pattern (file/folder) you must first remove it from the staging area, add it to `.gitignore` and commit your changes

```
# remove any committed file. 
git rm -r --cached <file>

# remove any committed directory and all its content.  (-rf for recursive)
git rm -rf --cached <folder>
```

[image]

If you wish to totally remove the content form your repository without leaving any undesired committed content - use this tool

### BFG

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

.gitignore will only prevent this file from being added, but it is already in the repository.  You have to remove the files from your repository.  The following link has more information:

[Gitignore not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436312/gitignore-not-working/25436481][1])