# Updating .gitignore messed up AndroidStudio. Is there a way to reverse this?

Tags: android, android-studio

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436312/gitignore-not-working) advice to help get my .gitignore working. After I ran the commands, the gitignore was working, but Android Studio went completely haywire, possibly because I deleted some cached files with that command.

I have issues like this:
[image]

In red, you can see how the `ApplicationTools` class isn't showing up, despite being right there in the project explorer. In blue, The `NotificationHelper` class is used at the bottom, but Android Studio is marking it as if it's not.

This is a very weird problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidStudio -> invalidate caches & restart