# disable future commits to a specific file

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to figure out a way to keep a file in a repository and just not track future changes to it.

[Gitignore not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436312/gitignore-not-working) and https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore lead me to believe that this is not possible, because the file is in the repository.  Thus my question is, is there a way to ignore future changes to a file that we need, but just want to keep individuals from unintentionally editing it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+commit+file+ignore+future+changes

Comment: `git update-index --skip-worktree FILENAME` for everyone in the team. There is no centralised way.