# How to add Larvel Log file in gitignore

Tags: laravel, git, vue.js, gitignore

```
/storage/logs/laravel.log
```

I Added this Code But it's Not Working. Your Help will be Appreciated

Comment: Laravel ignores its log files by default, if you didn't delete ".gitignore" file in storage/logs folder.

Answer (score 4):

```
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
.env
.env.backup
.phpunit.result.cache
docker-compose.override.yml
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
/.idea
/.vscode
```

Here is .gitignore file provided by Laravel.

However, If you already commited your storage folder delete them from github first so the git won't track them.

This is my .env customised:

```
vendor/
!public/vendor
node_modules/
npm-debug.log
.php_cs.cache

# Laravel 5 & Lumen specific
public/storage
public/hot
storage/*.key
storage/clockwork
.env.*.php
.env.php
.env
.env-production
Homestead.yaml
Homestead.json
.phpunit.result.cache
coverage/**

# Rocketeer PHP task runner and deployment package. https://github.com/rocketeers/rocketeer
.rocketeer/

# Phpstorm
.idea
_ide_helper.php
_ide_helper_models.php
.phpstorm.meta.php
.DS_Store
app/Repositories/Interfaces/UserRepositoryInterface
app/Repositories/UserRepository
App\Repositories\UserRepository
App\Repositories\Interfaces\UserRepositoryInterface
# Elastic Beanstalk Files
.elasticbeanstalk/*
!.elasticbeanstalk/*.cfg.yml
!.elasticbeanstalk/*.global.yml
storage/app/*
/tmp/
.vscode/settings.json
.php-cs-fixer.cache
```

Comment: You can add this link as an explanation on how to delete the created logs - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436312/gitignore-not-working