# Add file to ignored and remove it from the remote repository

Tags: intellij-idea, gitignore

I have a following case:

I made a `.gitignore` on `gitignore.io`. The `.idea` folder and `project_name.iml` were not in the ignore list and were pushed into the repo. I added them into the `.gitignore`, but they remain in the repo. If I make any changes to them, they appear in the list of changed  files to commit.
There is a way to get rid of them through the terminal

```
git rm -r --cached .idea/
```

But is it possible to start ignoring changes in those files and remove them from the repo by the IDE without using terminal?

Comment: You need to first remove them from the repo and commit, after which point the .gitignore will start working as you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gitignore not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436312/gitignore-not-working)

Comment: (To get an IDE-specific answer, avoid the generic [tag:git] tag.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove the file/folder in Project tool window via the "del" key:
2. Invoke "Undo" action to get them back. You will be asked if you want to add the files to git.
3. Click "NO"
4. Commit changes. The removed/re-added folder will be removed from git in the scope of this commit.

Here is the short video demonstrating the process:
[image]