# Github problems with project files

Tags: c#, file, github

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8psOI.png)

What's wrong with this file? I tried add .obj to gitignore file but that's doesn't helped.
Also i don't even changed anything in this file i think that's automatilcly changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have committed before adding the obj folder to the '.gitignore' file, you need to add the obj folder '.gitignore' and delete the obj folder as well, otherwise the obj folder will continue to be versioned [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436312/gitignore%20-not-working)