# How to ignore temporary files

Tags: git, gitkraken

I am using *GitKraken* and wonder if there is a way to ignore temporary files.

I haven't found something to do this. I tried it with a .gitignore file but it didn't work.

Comment: You need to clear the `cache` first.

Comment: Please clarify - what did you put to `.gitignore`, what did you expect to happen and what didn't work?

Comment: i tried this http://kleber-swf.com/the-definitive-gitignore-for-unity-projects/ but GitKraken still wants to push those files

Comment: @ Shravan40 how can i do this ?

Comment: @Yellown have you  commited your .gitignore file?

Comment: @ E.Doroskevic yes

Comment: what have you wrote in your .gitignore file? and have you previously commited the files which you now want to ignore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format your .gitignore using patterns described below.

**Exclude patterns**

```
example.mp4    # exclude a single file named example with .mp4 extension  
*.mp4          # exclude all files with .mp4 extension  
example/       # exclude folder named example  
example/*.log  # exclude all *.log files in example folder
```

After you've specified your patterns you need to commit your .gitignore

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Added git ignore file"
```

If you are already tracking a file and want to untrack it

**Untracking files**

```
git rm --cached example.log
```

The above command will delete file example.log from tracking BUT not from your local file system.

**Reference**

[Ignoring files](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/)

Comment: thx for your answer. Im currently not at my home PC so i cant test it but where can i open the shell (since now i used only the gui of GitKraken)

Comment: Git kraken must have git shell coming with it. So just check it out on your system

Comment: for some reason git was not installed (i tryed "git --version" in powershell) so i [installed](https://git-scm.com/download/win) git and did "git rm --cached -r ." & "git add ." 
with powershell in my Project directory but it is still not working.
When i open my project i get changes in  MyProject/Libary/CurrentLayout.dwlt for example

Comment: i also tried to remove all generated and temporary files and pushed. But when generating the new files gitkraken tracks them though i have the ignore file. Any clue what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: omg i got it :D i changed two things first i hat the wrong name my .gitignore was named unity.gitignore ([how to change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744305/how-to-create-gitignore-file)) and then i removed the first "/" so "/[Ll]ibrary/" turned to "[Ll]ibrary/"