# how to reset jupyter notebook meta data, keep content. So it will be easier to manage with git

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Is is possible to reset notebook run information, only keep content of a jupyter notebook? 
Because every time I run a notebook, git will think this file is changed. I don't remember if I change the content of this notebook(some time I open a notebook for days), so I can't just checkout this notebook file for git history. If I just commit notebook to git server no matter if I make "real" change of it, it makes my git log very messy.

There some execution information is not keep in **.ipynb_checkpints** directory:

for example:

[image]

another real messy content is the output of cells.

Answer (score -2):

You could add the following line to your .gitignore to simply make Git ignore the Jupyter Notebook checkpoint files:

```
.ipynb_checkpoints
```

If you don't already have a .gitignore file, this is a file that tells Git which files it can safely ignore. You can create it by simply making a file named ".gitignore", then adding the line above to the file.

If you're using Windows, this is a little harder than it should be, since the ".gitignore" file doesn't technically have a file name (only a file extension). [Here's how you can do it anyway.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744305/how-to-create-gitignore-file)

Also note that if you have already added any .ipynb_checkpoints files to your Git repo, you need to manually remove them before this will work. The .gitignore file does not work on files that are already tracked.

Comment: mynotebook.ipynb will change if I just run it without modify content. I take a look, it   keep some information of if I run this cell, something like that..actually I google it before I post his question, there are some tricks to make notebook work with git. but it's a bit complicated, So, I think if I am willing to discard some information, maybe there is a simpler solution.

Comment: Ah, you're right, looks like there's more than the checkpoint files. Here's a writeup that tries to tackle the problem, but I have not tried it myself: http://timstaley.co.uk/posts/making-git-and-jupyter-notebooks-play-nice/