# How to create a .tfignore file?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 (v15.9.9).

I can't seem to figure out how to create a .tfignore file.  If I do it manually, windows tells me I need to add a file name. And I am not seeing anywhere via the IDE to create one.

I'm used to GIT, where I can right click on a pending check-in file (that has changed) and just select "Ignore". But I don't seem to have that option, despite the fact that all the results I find via Google tell me that I should.

Comment: Technically not a dupe I guess since it's for a .gitignore, but should still work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744305/how-to-create-gitignore-file/53093031

Comment: @BrootsWaymb, can you make that an answer? :)

Comment: If you have a local workspace, you can add a new file and in the bottom of the pending changes window you have the changes you can 'promote'. In that window, you can right click the files to automatically add them to a .tfignore file that will be created for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved using the same steps as [How to create .gitignore file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744305/how-to-create-gitignore-file/53093031) (just replace .gitignore with .tfignore):

Create the text file tfignore.txt
Open it in a text editor and add your rules, then save and close
Hold SHIFT, right click the folder you're in, then select Open command window here
Then rename the file in the command line, with `ren tfignore.txt .tfignore`

*However*, an easier/quicker way to get around this Windows Explorer error is by appending a dot to the filename without extension: .tfignore. will be automatically changed to .tfignore

Comment: I edited your answer because `.tfsignore` is not the correct file name -- it is `.tfignore`. Note the lack of an "S".

Comment: Thanks @DanielMann. I'm only familiar with the .gitignore equivalent, so was just going off of the info in OP's post.

Answer (score 5):

You can create your file as `.tfignore.`. The last dot will be removed automatically.

Comment: This is the easiest way to implement. Very hepful :)

Answer (score 4):

the easiest way is to open command prompt and navigate to your project folder. Then

```
notepad .tfignore
```

after that just save file and you are good to go.

Or you can also use

```
echo "" > .tfignore
```

Note that you may need to manually include this file to TFS