# How to push the master changes into repository without including the modules changes in the push

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have an repository for my app: AppRepo
And inside, I have two modules:
- Site
- Time

Folder Structure:

```
.AppRepo  
    ├── Controller  
    ├── Routes  
    ├── Models  
    └── Modules  
        ├── Site  
        └── Time
```

And I need push all changes I do over AppRepo on your repository, but not including the Modules changes. The changes of modules , I want push to different repositories (one for each module).

But when I wish clone the AppRepo I want clone too the modules content...

Exist a configuration for GIT for this behaviour?
I can exclude the Modules Folder with .gitignore, but i want know if exist a better way.

Comment: I think you need submodule for this.

Comment: [tag:git-submodules], [tag:git-subtree], [tag:git-subrepo]

Comment: @Chuan I know, but when I want to press AppRepo, this  include changes of the modules, but each module have a own git-repo and I want push on this repos and not in master repo of the App

Answer (score 0):

Just create a .gitignore file in your AppRepo root and add the Modules/ in the file
[see how to create gitigrore file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744305/how-to-create-a-gitignore-file)