# Why is gitignore not working even after i put the file name in?

Tags: windows, github, gitignore

I have a file called sohuku.txt. I have another folder named .gitignore.txt inside which I have put 'sohuku.txt', but when I type 'git add .' in PowerShell and then type git status, it shows the file in changes to be committed. what to do?

Comment: Remove the extension from the file `.gitignore`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a .gitignore file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744305/how-to-create-a-gitignore-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create `.gitignore` file in your root `/` directory without any extension.

```
/
  src
     index.js
  .gitignore
```

want to remove the .txt files, just add in the `.gitignore` file

```
*.txt
```

and remove the old commit:

```
$ git reset HEAD~                                          
<< edit files as necessary >>                              
$ git add ...                                              
$ git commit -c ORIG_HEAD
```

[Undo git to learn more](https://devconnected.com/how-to-undo-last-git-commit/#:%7E:text=The%20easiest%20way%20to%20undo,removed%20from%20your%20Git%20history.)

Answer (score 2):

The `.gitignore` file should be at the root of the repository and named properly. https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 2):

The file has to be named `.gitignore`, not `.gitignore.txt`

If windows won't let you rename it (an error like "you must type a filename"), then rename it to `.gitignore.`

Answer (score 2):

gitignore is file, remove .txt from file name

.gitignore.txt -> .gitignore

Answer (score 2):

Don't put `.txt` on the `.gitignore` file...

So you can pass the file name that you don't want to push to git.