# How to make a .gitignore file in a git repository and add names of the Files/Folders in this .gitignore file so that git may not tracked these files

Tags: git, github, gitlab

### Git ##*As i am facing problem i have initialized git repository using

git init
but there is no git ignore file anyone who can guide me i want to make my git not to monitor some files like node modules folder etc
thanks in advance*

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744305/how-to-create-a-gitignore-file

Answer (score 0):

you can add the .gitignore file manually.
See there for usefull template: https://github.com/github/gitignore

Answer (score 0):

You can create the ignore file by `touch .gitignore` in git bash.
Here is a template ignore file for node:
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/7293c14345c205c679722364a01b88d331e862ff/Node.gitignore#L41