# Random Xcode files are modified/added/deleted in Git

Tags: ios, swift, git, github-desktop

I am using Github desktop to source control my app, but it keeps changing/deleting/adding all sorts of files that I did not touch, assets, pod files, and I do not know what is going on or how to stop it. Any help here?

I re-cloned my repo and still having the issue

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with iCloud sync, try turning that off

Answer (score 2):

They are build artefacts, Pods, and other things you should've excluded from your repo. Use gitignore.io to create a proper `.gitignore` file, and add it to root folder of your repo (e.g. [like this](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/xcode,swift)). Then delete all this junk from your repo.

I also recommend reading [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-source-control-preferences-in-xcode) on working with Source Control

Answer (score 1):

like sfgblackwarkrts already said these "random" files are artefacts, pods etc.
They will be created everytime you made any changes in one of them E.g. updating your pods, changing packages,..

To see how a .gitignore file can be created and managed, you can find a question and the correct answers to it on Stackoverflow.

[git - how to create a .gitignore file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744305/how-to-create-a-gitignore-file)

Comment: what would I put in the gitignore file to avoid the changes above?

Comment: you should but all files and pattern in your .gitignore that are generated by your build system. You ask yourself what files those are, right?
Typically you'll see them when you do some code submits on your project. You'll see some files will pop up again and again. 
Those are your build system-files.