# how to create json object and set it in a post body in ios using asi http request

Tags: ios

```
NSString *loginurl =[NSString
                     stringWithFormat:@"/ajax/useraccount.aspx/methodname"]
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:loginPath];

NSString *loginPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",singleton.website,loginurl];

asiRequest = [[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url] retain];
[asiRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
[asiRequest addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
[asiRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

NSDictionary *tmp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"email", @"Email",
                     @"fname", @"FirstName", nil];
NSError *error;
NSData *postdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tmp options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"this is value %@",postdata);
NSMutableData *mutablePostData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:postdata];


[asiRequest setPostBody:mutablePostData];
[asiRequest setDelegate:self];
[asiRequest setTimeOutSeconds:60];
[asiRequest startAsynchronous];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

i want create this type of object and set it in a post body
{"objectRequest":{"email":"Email","fname":"FirstName"}}

i am unable to hit the method am i missing something or is there is another way to create this type of json object and set it in a post body thank you in advance

Comment: You don't need the "" around the key on the object. You should just use {objectRequest:{email:"Email",fname:"FirstName"}}

Comment: i have tried this as well but not working i:e                NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\registartionrequest:{\"Email\":\"%@\",\"FirstName\":\"%@\"}}",@"test",@"test"];
    NSLog(@"Request: %@", jsonRequest);
    NSData *postData =[[NSStringstringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonRequest] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Answer (score 0):

You can really just return that string as a body if you like. But you have to set the content type to ["application/json"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type). One of these posts might help for doing that on ios?

[How to set content-type when using initWithContentsOfUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323817/how-to-set-content-type-when-using-initwithcontentsofurl)

[JSON file set content type to application/json AFNetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164486/json-file-set-content-type-to-application-json-afnetworking)

[setting content-type overwriting httpbody?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254046/setting-content-type-overwriting-httpbody)

Comment: i am already setting its content-type to application/json
[asiRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
[asiRequest addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks ok with your code except you forgot to call `buildPostBody` method. After you set all body data you have to call this method.

```
[asiRequest buildPostBody];
[asiRequest startAsynchronous];
```

If this is a new project, I highly recommend to use any other up-to-date libraries. developers stopped developing ASIHTTPRequest long time ago.